# react-select: While using multi select, how to persist the contents of input box?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) for rendering a multi select box. When I type something, it displays a dropdown of options according to the text I typed. When I select one option, the text which I entered in the input box doesn't persist. Is there a way to make it persist there even after a selection?

Comment: Did you try to implement the `onChange` function to save the value when react-select value changed?

Comment: My `onChange` function stores the value which was selected in the redux store and it is coming through props from a smart component. Where do I exactly store the `value` which was just entered in the inputbox?

Comment: Either in the `state` of the component that displays the react-select field, or in third parties like another redux state dedicated to Forms( see [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/) )

Comment: I tried this but I don't think it supports retaining of the `inputValue`.

I found this after going through all optional params in react-select. I went through the source code and found that they are resetting it. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/lib/Select.js#L664

Comment: I have forked the repo and commented the above line and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/lib/Select.js#L664

I  have forked the repo and commented the above line and it works fine for me.